# My registered apps are not showing in my profile; where can I find them?

Tags: support, api, api-key, registration

I registered two apps in Stack Apps, but when I access my account, it shows no registered apps.

How can I mark them as my apps and how can access app settings (client id, key), etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can **see your apps, that you registered** with [the registration page](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register), by going to:

## [stackapps.com/apps/oauth](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/)

This page is different for every user and you will be forced to log-in to see it.

---

The only place I have ever found this link is in a sidebar on [Stack App's home page](https://stackapps.com/):

> [image: Link to manage your applications]