# Where can I find a link to my apps and API keys?

Tags: support, stackapps

I feel pretty stupid but it's taken me about 15 minutes to find any reference to the app and api key I've created. I started searching through my profile page but couldn't find anything. I also came across [this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/4831/my-registered-apps-are-not-showing-in-my-profile-where-can-i-find-them) ([rev. 1 when this was posted](https://stackapps.com/revisions/4832/1)), which instead lists apps I've logged into using my stack exchange auth, rather than apps I've created. Incidentally it seems a fairly obscure place to put it. Finally [this post](https://stackapps.com/a/5019/33965) pointed me to [**/apps/oauth/**](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/). Is there a link to there that I've been missing?

Comment: This question is answered in [one of the posts you linked](http://stackapps.com/a/4832/7653).  I also just added additional information there.

Comment: Aah, thnaks. The original answer didn't have that information (as linked) but it's quite clear now.